# How to define the number of RSU in VEINS simulation

Tags: veins

I am new to the veins environment and trying to simulate a vehicular network with various number of vehicles and RSUs but I have challenge to define the number of RSU.

I succeeded to define the number of vehicles but still not for RSUs.